# Gluon iOS Application delivery Errors

Tags: ios, iphone, javafxports, gluon-mobile

Hi I'm using the application loader to load my app into TestFlight but I keep getting 3 errors and I don't know how to handle them.

> Error ITMS-90096 Your binary is not optimised for iPhone 5 - new apps must include support for a 4inch display and must include a launch image with a -568h size modifier. (Paraphrased)
>
> Error ITMS-90475 Invalid Bundle. iPad multitasking support requires a launch story board in bundle.
>
> Error ITMS-90208 Invalid Bundle. The bundle does not support the minimum OS version specified in the info.plist.

I've tried adding setting the minimum OS version in plist but then it tells me it's a pkg or mpkg not an ipa file, even though the file extension is .ipa. I have no idea how to fix the others.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.6'
    
}
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
    url     'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    
}

}

mainClassName = 'com.nopanicsselfhelper.NoPanicsSelfHelper'

dependencies {
compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.2'

}

jfxmobile {

downConfig {
    
    version = '3.2.4'
    // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
    plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
}

android {
    signingConfig {
        storeFile file("x")
        storePassword 'x'
        keyAlias 'x'
        keyPassword 'x'
    }        
    applicationPackage = 'com.nopanicsselfhelper.NoPanicsSelfHelper.java'
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    resDirectory = 'src/android/res'
}
ios {
    
    infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    forceLinkClasses = [
            'com.gluonhq.**.*',
            'javax.annotations.**.*',
            'javax.inject.**.*',
            'javax.json.**.*',
            'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
    ]
    iosSignIdentity = "x"
    iosProvisioningProfile = "x"
    arch = "arm64"
    }
}
```

[default-info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qQh0.png)

Comment: I've solved 90475 by requiring full screen and i think i'm getting there with 90096 i've got the required image file now. I'm just trying to place them correctly and checking anything needed for the plist.

Comment: 90208 and 90475 are currently solved 90096 is still outstanding. If I fix it all I will add an answer with the fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 90208 was solved by adding the MInimumOSVersion to my default
-info.plist. - This isn't something that would be done in an Xcode project but I think it's necessary in a gluon project from what I have worked out along the way. Using the recommended LSMinimum option or the MinimumSystemVersion would result in another error.

Error 90475 was solved by requiring full screen by adding UIRequiresFullScreen with the string YES to the plist.

Error 90096 was solved by adding back the various required files that Gluon had provided that started with the name default.